# splitting the actions and reducers into different files

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to do an API call through reducer.My code is working fine [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-async-actions-kjqk0) but the problem is all the actions, reducers are inside same file. So I tried to separate the reducer and actions in different file, but it is not working. I have debugged by putting some console.log but it is not helping me. Can anyone tell me how to fix it? I am providing my code snippet and sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-async-actions-os6nu

```or-tag-here
import {
  SELECT_CHANNEL,
  REQUEST_POSTS,
  RECEIVE_POSTS,
  DISPLAY_ALERT
} from "../actions";
//const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
const fetchReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_DATA_START:
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: true,
        fetchingMessage: "fetch data start"
      };
    case RECEIVED_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: false,
        fetched: true,
        data: action.payload,
        fetchingMessage: "received data"
      };
    case FETCH_DATA_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: false,
        error: action.payload,
        fetchingMessage: "fetch data error"
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default fetchReducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your state in the main `reducer` file as well as use the same action name across all your application. I have also used `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` methods to make it easy and simple to use redux with react (https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react).

Reducer file

```js
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { REQUEST_POSTS, RECEIVE_POSTS } from "../actions";

const initialState = {
  fetching: false,
  fetched: false,
  data: [],
  error: null,
  fetchingMessage: ""
};

const fetchReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST_POSTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: true,
        fetchingMessage: "fetch data start"
      };
    case RECEIVE_POSTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: false,
        fetched: true,
        data: action.payload,
        fetchingMessage: "received data"
      };
    case "FETCH_DATA_ERROR":
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: false,
        error: action.payload,
        fetchingMessage: "fetch data error"
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default combineReducers({ posts: fetchReducer });
```

App.js

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
 return {
    data: state.posts
 };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
 return {
  onFetch: () => {
   dispatch(requestPosts);
  },
  onFetchSuccess: data => {
   dispatch(receivedPosts(data));
  }
  // onFetchError: () => {
  //   // dispatch()
  // }
};
};
export default connect(
 mapStateToProps,
 mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

Here is the working demo link forked from your CodeSandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-async-actions-436qu). Let me know if you do not understand anything.

Comment: hey thanks for your reply...you forgot to include the sandbox link :(

Comment: ohh. my bad. I have updated my answer. check it out.

Comment: hey can you update comments in the code, its very hard to understand :(

Comment: I have removed the extra code which was present in your original link. Let me know if anything is missing.

Comment: hey still the api call is not moved to actions file, can you let me know how to move to actions file. I tried not working :( `<FetchButton
          onFetchClick={() => {
            this.props.onFetch();
            axios `